# NSImage drawAtPoint lost quality

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsimage

I have a monochrome picture,When i draw this picture to another picture, it become a gray picture.

Here is my code:

Save a monochrome picture:

```
        NSImage *copyImage = [image copy];  // Copy from a monochrome picture
        NSBitmapImageRep *copyrep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[copyImage TIFFRepresentation]];
        NSSize copySize;
        copySize.width = 72.0 * [copyrep pixelsWide] / PRINT_DPI;  //Set Printing DPI
        copySize.height = 72.0 * [copyrep pixelsHigh] / PRINT_DPI; //Set Printing DPI
        [copyrep setSize:copySize];
        copyImage= [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[copyrep TIFFRepresentation]];
        NSData *imgData = [copyImage TIFFRepresentation];
        [imgData writeToFile: @"/Users/bbmac/Desktop/1.png" atomically: NO]; // save for testing
```

But when i draw it to a big picture, it become a gray picture:

```
// for printing
NSImage *printImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:imageSize];
[printImage lockFocus];

// Draw a monochrome picture
[image drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(newX, newY) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0f];

[printImage unlockFocus]; 
// Save for testing
[[printImage TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile: @"/Users/bbmac/Desktop/printImage.png" atomically: NO];
```

Comment: Your dpi calculation is wrong. If at all it must be PRINT_DPI/72.0 * current-size.

Comment: However, the wrong undrstanding of dpi is not the issue. What is the acutal value of copySize when the size is set to copyrep? If that happens to be very small then the result can easiyl plain gray when the image is scaled up later.

Comment: I think you are waisting time and memory by copying the image data to often. But that, too, is not the reason for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the copyImage is just for testing. the saved file from copyImage is a real monochrome picture.

Comment: copySize: Before set dpi : 264 × 299   after: 63 × 71

Comment: As I said, turn the dpi adjustment around.

Comment: the dpi just for the printing. It is noting to do with the quality.I remove the dpi setting, it still can save a monochrome picture file.

Comment: I cannot help unless you try to understand the purpose of dpi and what you are currently doing with it. If it was just for the printing then you would not need to resize the image at all and leave the intprolation to the printer.